# How to program to repaint every second item in recyclerview to a different color? (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, background-color

My RecyclerView is having some elements in it. Every second element should be painted in a different color. This is my function.

```
val BackgroundElemnt: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container1)
    fun bind(currencyPost: CurrencyPost){
                if (BackgroundElemnt.get(position)%2 == 0){
                    BackgroundElemnt.setBackgroundColor(0xB8B8B8)
                }
                else
                {
                    BackgroundElemnt.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF)
                }
                CName.text = currencyPost.Name
                CValue.text = currencyPost.Value
            }
```

Comment: Use a handler that runs forever

Comment: Do you mean "every other element"? A couple of people here interpreted that you want the color to change once per second of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
you should try this

```
val backgroundElement: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container1)
    fun bind(currencyPost: CurrencyPost){
                if (position%2 == 0){
                    backgroundElement.setBackgroundColor(0xB8B8B8)
                }
                else
                {
                    backgroundElement.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF)
                }
                CName.text = currencyPost.Name
                CValue.text = currencyPost.Value
            }
```

I replaced  `if (BackgroundElemnt.get(position)%2 == 0)` with `if (position%2 == 0)` because you're checking for the position of the item in the adapter not the position of the root view.

Solution 2:

You should create a flag in your model that decides what the colour should be, then you should modify your list item set the colour for every second item.

Example:

```
data class CurrencyPost(val id: Int, val name: String, val hasDifferentColour: Boolean = false)
```

assuming that is the model of the item, you should then convert your list item to indicate what colour it should be. So before you call adapter.submitList(listOfCurrencyPost)
you should map the items to show the colour

so

```
 val modifiedListOfCountryPost =
        listOfCurrencyPost.mapIndexed { countryPost, index ->
            if (index % 2 == 0) countryPost.copy(hasDifferentColour = true)
        }
```

then adapter.submit(modifiedListOfCountryPost)

in the onBind method of your adapter you should then do this

```
fun bind(currencyPost: CurrencyPost){
                if (countryPost.hasDifferentColur){
                    BackgroundElemnt.setBackgroundColor(0xB8B8B8)
                }else
                {
                    BackgroundElemnt.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF)
                }
                CName.text = currencyPost.Name
                CValue.text = currencyPost.Value
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution helped.
But I changed 
`BackgroundElemnt.setBackgroundColor (0xB8B8B8)`
to 
`BackgroundElement.setBackgroundColor (Color.rgb (132,209,152))`

Answer (score 0):

Integer timeOut = 1000;

```
public void AlterColor(){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // put your condition statement here
                    finish();
                }
            },timeOut);

try this out...placae it in your class and call it within the main method.
```

Comment: PS: this is in java kindly switch it to Kotlin